# How to use #Polymer core-animated-pages transitions to tile-cascade custom elements?

Tags: html, polymer, material-design, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am trying to replicate the slide-up and tile-cascade transitions seen [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/preview.html#aa77403f15564b02dc2d) using this [jist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ocorso/8385b7fb5ec46dfbee49/raw/3fcc7396997bc6451c9c234e6cd7eec2d31b638b/designer.html) with the [polymer designer tool](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/)

The difference here is I want to use custom elements instead of  tags. I created custom elements for each page and placed them all within a core-animated-pages.

I want all a grid of cards inside one of the pages to tile-cascade down and the core-scroll-header to slide-up just like in the above jist but every way I try to nest the  tags to put the transition attributes on the desired children, nothing works. The only thing that works is setting the core-animated-pages transitions attribute to "cross-fade-all." Very frustrating since documentation/examples on tile-cascade is scarce.

- Example site: http://marissageoffroy.ored.net
- Github repo: https://github.com/ocorso/marissageoffroy

Answer (score 0):

Message from Arthur off the [Polymer Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/DFzyauBz3t0):

This puzzled me, too, until I cracked open the tile-cascade file:

https://github.com/Polymer/core-animated-pages/blob/master/transitions/tile-cascade.html

Look in there, and you'll see that the transitions require each tile to be a .

The quick solution here is just to wrap each of your core-cards in a .

There is an open issue about this: https://github.com/Polymer/core-animated-pages/issues/14

You might want to follow that issue for updates.

Thanks,
Arthur